# Xero API Integration - How to get Tenant Id?

Tags: xero-api

We have created a demo company and got the Client id and client secret id in Xero API Portal. We have generated the Auth code using postman tool. We are trying to further hit the other Invoice related APIs like 'create contact', 'invoice' etc.

We have tried calling other APIs (create invoice, contact etc) from Xero API Explorer. We have successfully done that, In API Explorer there are by default authorization code and Tenant id.

But we are not able to get the tenant id from our Demo company of Xero portal using Postman tool.
Please help us to get the tenant id ??

I have tried to call the "https://api.xero.com/connections" with Bearer Authorization code.
**Expected: we should get the corresponding Tenant Id.**

But instead getting error 403

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there may be an error with the request eg the access token may be expired. In order to troubleshoot this more accurately, please can you raise a case with Xero Support [here](https://developer.xero.com/contact-xero-developer-platform-support) and include your client id and the date, time and timezone for the most recent 403 error